# configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs. when installing libtools-2.4.2

Tags: macos, compilation, homebrew, configure, automake

Have been struggling to set up my environment to run bioinformatics tools. The issue started with a consistent *autogen.sh* error in `autoreconf -fi: command not found` for multiple applications. Reinstalled autoconf, automake, libtools.

Currently, *libtools* installation fails at ./configure, but `autoconf` and *automake* installed successfully.
Here is the error:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... libltdl/config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0
configure: autobuild project... GNU Libtool
configure: autobuild revision... 2.4.2 ()
configure: autobuild hostname... MACUSR
configure: autobuild mode... default
configure: autobuild timestamp... 2019011
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/usr/local/libtool-2.4.2':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
```

Tried Homebrew, it installed all my tools in usr/local/Cellar and nothing runs, I have added tool locations to my PATH variable, but no luck. Traced problem to jamf issue:
https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/28764/jamf-quickadd-symlinks-usr-local-bin-causing-install-problems-for-other-apps

Stuck and will be happy for an advice here.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it was an old gcc problem. My PATH referenced to anaconda3/bin first, where it was triggering whatever gcc it found there. After changing my $PATH to point to other bins before anaconda3, everything compiled without issues.

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```