# FreeBSD " configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs "

Tags: php, unix, gcc, freebsd, pecl

I am trying to install PECL extension " PHAR " in my FreeBSD ( pfSense edition ) using phpize . when I try to run " ./configure " I get this

[image]

note that Im just following PHP documentation and when searching about this error it is the first time I hear about cross compiler. so am not trying to cross compile.

any ideas ?

Comment: Why don't you use PHAR available as a binary package or at least build [PHAR](https://www.freshports.org/archivers/php74-phar/) using [FreeBSD ports](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html)?

Comment: In pfSense edition there's no ports actually ...

Comment: This might be better off on superuser, but it sounds like there might be an issue with the compiler.

Comment: I checked if gcc actually exists in PATH and I found it pathed correctly. Im not used to FreeBSD so when I tried to export ld_library_path , I didn't even find that variable l

Comment: One link suggest an old version of gcc (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132502/configure-error-cannot-run-c-compiled-programs-when-installing-libtools-2-4-2), another mentions adding gcc to the path (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943461/configure-error-cannot-run-c-compiled-programs)

Comment: This mentions dev tools (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173714/cabal-error-cannot-run-c-compiled-programs), as does this one, which is related to pecl (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23901/cannot-run-c-compiled-programs-error-when-installing-pdo-php-module)

Comment: You should try to use the package if you can. If not, please post the config.log.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way around to solve this problem :
at first , when trying to install the available **PHAR** package with **pkg** I couldn't find any and thats because pfSense dev team have disabled the FreeBSD repos. I went and enabled it under `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos`and then I just typed `pkg install php72.phar`

thanks everyone in comments !